# How to fix CAN Bit Stuffing Error

Tags: can

Our ADAS Controller is based on Renesas RH850/U2A16 Microcontrollers.  We are using Infineon TLE9255WSK Partial Network CAN Transceivers.  We are using Vector CANoe Professional.

When a CAN message is transmitted on CAN Channel 2 from our controller to Vector CANoe, there is Bit Stuffing Error.  Please see attached filename Bit_Stuffing_error_CAN_Trace.PNG.

Also, attached are files that show our Vector CANoe tool configuration.

We are using 120 Ohms termination resistor.

What might be the problem?  Is the problem in Vector CANoe Tool configuration?  Or is this problem in CAN Driver source code in our controller?[![Bit Stuffing Error CAN Trace[[image: CANoe Configuration][1]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyAm7.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMhh6.png)

[image: CANoe configuration][image: CANoe_NW_HW_configuration]

Comment: Use an oscilloscope to verify what is actually happening on the wire.

Comment: What is the physical distance between the nodes?

Comment: "We are using 120 Ohms termination resistor." As in singular? Not resistor**s**, two of them? Do you measure 60 ohms across CANH and CANL?

Comment: A sampling point at 75% and just 8 cycles with 500kbps is fishy, though just within timing specs. There shouldn't be a need for such weird settings if you have a 16MHz oscillator. Whoever set up the tq for your baudrates didn't know what they were doing. Aim for 16tq with 87.5% sample point. As for stuffing errors, that's what you typically get when there are error frames on the bus. Check [What are the most common causes of CAN bus communication errors?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276251).

Comment: Why multiple senders might cause this problem?

Assuming senders are causing this problem, how to debug it?

The problem occurs with Two specific standard CAN Ids. One is transmitted on CAN 1 to Vector CANoe tool and the other is transmitted on CAN 2 to Vector CANoe tool.